# Count difference between distinct and join over distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2, distinct

How do I count the number of distinct rows minus a join over those same distinct rows?

I'm writing after triggers where I need to raise an error if the user does not have rights to the rows submitted. I can do this in two statements but this seems inefficient.

```
DECLARE @AccessibleCount INT =
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT i.[ParentId])
    FROM
        inserted i
    INNER JOIN [SuperSecret].[Parent] AS p ON
        p.[Id] = i.[ParentId] AND
        p.[LockedBy] = @UserId
);

DECLARE @ActualCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [ParentId]) FROM inserted);
IF (@AccessibleCount <> @ActualCount)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(...);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
```

For performance sake, it seems like I should use a subquery over the distinct inserted.ParentId for both counts. I tried the following but it resulted in "Invalid object name 'i'."

```
DECLARE @ActualMinusAccessible INT =
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
            -
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                i
            INNER JOIN [SuperSecret].[Parent] AS p ON
                p.[Id] = i.[ParentId] AND
                p.[LockedBy] = @UserId
        )
    FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT [ParentId] FROM inserted
        ) AS i
);

IF (@ActualMinusAccessible <> 0)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR (...);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If am not wrong you want to `Raise Error` if a `[ParentId]` is **inserted** which is not present in `[SuperSecret].[Parent]` table. Try changing your SQL query like this.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   inserted i
           WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM   [SuperSecret].[Parent] a
                              WHERE  i.[ParentId] = a.[ParentId] AND a.[LockedBy] = @UserId))
  BEGIN
      RAISERROR (...);
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  END
```

OR

```
IF (SELECT Count(DISTINCT [ParentId]) - (SELECT Count(DISTINCT i.[ParentId])
                                         FROM   inserted i
                                                INNER JOIN [SuperSecret].[Parent] AS p
                                                        ON p.[Id] = i.[ParentId]
                                                           AND p.[LockedBy] = @UserId)
    FROM   inserted) <> 0
  BEGIN
      RAISERROR (...);
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  END
```

Comment: @user1546077 - yes it is wrong you cannot refer the alias (i) there. try executing my answer

Comment: thanks, the first query's actual execution plan is better than the second. the second query's actual execution plan performs similarly to the original query but most likely better in some (many?) circumstances.